# unknown filesystem after partition change

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, filesystem

I have got Windows 10 and Ubuntu partitions Dualbooted on my laptop. When installing, i left some unallocated room. 
Using Windows, i have made a new partition from the unallocated space to move some files around. Worked out fine, but after rebooting my laptop, i get

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Typing

```
ls
```

gives me

```
(hd0) (hd0, msdos4) (hd0, msdos3) (hd0, msdos2) (hd0, msdos1)
```

but when i try to locate my grub folder, it says

```
ls (hd0,msdos4)
(hd0, msdos4): Filesystem is unknown.
```

With every partition! 
Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Windows' partitioning tools have a tendency to convert from a standard [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)  (aka *basic disk*) configuration to a Windows [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) configuration atop MBR (aka *dynamic disk*) when asked to create partitions beyond four. In doing so, your setup, which probably started either with four primary partitions or three primary partitions plus some number of logical partitions, has been converted to a form that GRUB can't read -- or at the very least, that GRUB cannot read given its current configuration.

Although there are Linux tools to read LDM disks, I'm unaware of any official way to boot Ubuntu from such a disk. If you're lucky, you might find a recovery procedure that will enable you to use the disk as it is; however, the usual approach to fixing this problem is to undo the conversion to LDM. AFAIK, there are no Linux tools designed explicitly to do this. The safest approach is to use a Windows tool, such as the [AOMEI disk converter](http://www.disk-partition.com/features/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html) or [EaseUS Partition Manager.](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk.htm) Note, however, that I've never used these tools for this purpose, so I can't say how well they work. Given the potentially catastrophic consequences of getting it wrong, I *strongly* recommend that you research these tools before using them, and create adequate backups of your installations, or at least your user data, before proceeding.

An alternative to converting the existing setup is to re-install everything from scratch. This, of course, will also require adequate backups of your personal data so you can restore the data when you're done.

In the future, you would be wise to keep Windows Partitioning Rule Number One in mind:

***Windows Partitioning Rule #1:*** The standard Windows GUI partitioning tool is ***FLAKY*** and therefore ***DANGEROUS***, particularly on MBR disks with extended/logical partitions. It's known to do unwanted conversions to an LDM setup and to modify primary/logical assignments in such a way as to put primary partitions in the middle of an extended partition, which is completely illegal and likely to cause data loss, particularly if you're unwary in the future.

In the future, I strongly recommend using Linux tools or third-party Windows tools for all your partitioning. About the only thing the standard Windows GUI tool is good for is shrinking an NTFS partition, which it may arguably be better at than Linux tools because NTFS is a proprietary filesystem, and GParted's support for shrinking NTFS is based on a reverse engineering of that filesystem. Even so, the risk of using the standard Windows tool is significant, particularly if you try creating a new partition in the space you've freed or if the disk already has logical partitions. (Note that the Windows tool doesn't even properly identify logical partitions as such; it claims they're primary.)